# unable to use hibernate group by in hibernate criteria in java

Tags: hibernate, group-by

I am having three bean classes as User,UserImages and UserLocation as :

```
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    String userName;

    ....
    ....

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
    private UserLocation userLocationObj;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserImages> userImages ;

}



public class UserImages {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    @Column(name="user_id" , insertable=false , updatable=false)
    Long userId;

    @Column(name="pic_url")
    String picUrl;

    ....
    ....

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
}



public class UserLocation implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name="user_id" , insertable=false , updatable=false)
    Long userId;

    ....
    ....

     @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     private User user;
}
```

I am having around 20 columns in User.
I am trying to use join and getting all the records of all the users which are having location and images using Hibernate Criteria but unfortunately I am not able to use group by clause in that. 
I googled and found solutions indicating to use Projection's groupProperty but if I am using it , it is giving only the id of the User table and all the data of other table.
But I want all the data of User as well as other tables.Currently this is how I am trying to do without groupProperty:

```
public List<User> getTravellersNearMe(Session session) {

   Criteria parentCriteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
   Criteria firstChildCriteria = parentCriteria.createCriteria("userLocationObj", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
   Criteria secondChildCriteria = parentCriteria.createCriteria("userImages", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

   parentCriteria.setFirstResult(start);
   parentCriteria.setMaxResults(record);

   List<User> searchResults = (ArrayList<User>) parentCriteria.list();
   return searchResults;
}
```

By using this way I am getting duplicate records because of join.

This is how I am trying to do with groupProperty:

public List getTravellersNearMe(Session session) {

```
   Criteria parentCriteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
   Criteria firstChildCriteria = parentCriteria.createCriteria("userLocationObj", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
   Criteria secondChildCriteria = parentCriteria.createCriteria("userImages", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);

   parentCriteria.setFirstResult(start);
   parentCriteria.setMaxResults(record);
   parentCriteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("id"))); 

   List<User> searchResults = (ArrayList<User>) parentCriteria.list();
   return searchResults;
}
```

By this way I am only getting the id from the User table and all the data from other two tables. But I want all the data from all three tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main point is to use the groupProperty(), and the related aggregate functions provided by the Projections class.

For Example:

```
 SELECT column_name, max(column_name) , min (column_name) , count(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name > xxxxx
GROUP BY column_name
```

Its equivalent criteria object is :

```
List result = session.createCriteria(SomeTable.class)       
                    .add(Restrictions.ge("someColumn", xxxxx))      
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.groupProperty("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.max("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.min("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.count("someColumn"))           
                    ).list();
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the question correctly.I asked how to get all data of all the tables by using group by in hibernate criteria. Your solution only gives specific columns.